# Scaling notification emails to mobile devices

Tags: iphone, html, css, email, mobile

I've have my notification emails styled with a wrapper div that has a fixed width of 600px, and it looks great on desktops.  My problem is that when it loads on the iPhone/mobile devices, it doesn't "set it's scale" so the whole email is in the view - it displays at a 1:1 scale so part of the email is cut off on the initial load.

Is there anyway to set a CSS value that causes mobile devices to scale the content appropriately, the same way it scales a website to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what type of content you have in your email notification, but you could use dynamic widths (% instead of px) so the email adapts to every screen. But then you will have to make sure the contents are also well adapted to mobile widths; or
I'm not sure if there is a way to detect what device the user is coming from, and choose different htmls depending on this.